# Does proving that two lines are parallel require a postulate?

Tags: geometry

Harold Jocobs' Geometry book(2nd Ed) has a Theorem that states "If two lines form equal corresponding angles with a transversal, then the lines are parallel," and gives a indirect proof. He assumes that the lines are not parallel and shows this assumption leads to a contradiction(since if the lines intersect, the angles are not congruent).

Another textbook(McDougal Littell's Geometry) have Corresponding Angles Postulate that says "If two parallel lines are cut by a transversal then the pairs of corresponding angles are congurent."

The two statements are converse, but Jacobs' book doesn't use a postulate to prove other parallel lines theorems.

Sould the Corresponding Angles Postulate be a theorem, and not a postulate? If it can be proved by indirect proof, shouldn't it be just a theorem like the one in Jacobs' book?

I understand the indirect proof of Jacobs' Theorem, but why do other books use a postulate?

Comment: In hyperbolic non- euclidean geometry where lines are geodesic and corresponding angles equal they are parallel. Any two conditions imply the third.

Comment: Narasimham, thank you very much for your commnt!! Your comment is complicated for me... But, in Euclidean geometry, is a postulate needed to prove two lines are parallel? Why does one book start with a postulate, and another book never uses a postulate?

Comment: @Narasimham If your comment were an answer I would downvote it. It doesn't answer the question and introduces complications that don't help illuminate the problem.

Comment: Let me put it in perspective. Yes, I too don't justify it. That we are so close to fifth postulate that was  invoked for non-euclidean geometry is a matter not entirely irrelevant here. However, I shall delete the comment soon.if someone had told me the water is deep here at an early stage, it would be remembered for long  as a watershed situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are considering two **different** theorems:

(1) If two lines form equal corresponding angles with a transversal, then the lines are parallel.

(2) If two lines are parallel, then they form equal corresponding angles with a transversal.

In euclidean geometry, you need an additional postulate to prove theorem (2) (the famous "Euclid's fifth postulate"), while that is not needed to prove theorem (1).

Comment: needing an additional postulate to prove theorem (2) above is a great info!! Thank you very much. Then, is it safe to say that (2) is like a postulate, and that (1) is a theorem since it can be proved by contradiction?

Comment: Thank you very much for making my questions more clear!!

Comment: @chris, yes, you can take (2) as a postulate instead of Euclid's fifth postulate, but that's a matter of choice. Most textbooks take instead as a postulate the so called "uniqueness of parallel": given a line $r$ and an external point $P$, there is **only one** line in the plane passing through $P$ and parallel to $r$. From that you can prove (2).

Comment: your answer is very clear!! Now I understand it. Thank you very much for the additional answer!!